# Change Border Width of UISegmentedControl in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I change the border width of a `UISegmentedControl` in iOS 8? Currently, the border width is 2px, and I would like to set it to 1px. Setting the CALayer's border width did not seem to work. I cannot seem to find anything about this anywhere.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use custom divider images depending on your needs:

```
[mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image1 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:barMetrics];
[mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image2 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:barMetrics];
[mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image3 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal                   rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:barMetrics];
```

Check the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html

Comment: Hi MatterGoal, and thanks for the answer! I decided to set the background image of the entire SegmentedControl to replace the border. I will also be using custom divider images. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Alexander you're wellcome ... you can accept the answer if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 3):

This works with iOS 8.1

```
   _segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth = 2;
```

Comment: Please add some details about your proposed solution. you may understand but the person asking may not. Thanks

Comment: I just realised he is talking about Swift and not Objective-C. So my solution applies to the latter. There isn't any more to explain than that line of code?

Comment: Thank you for answering, Tander. Unfortunately, I've already tried setting the layer's borderWidth, and this did not resolve the issue. Doing so simply overlays a border on top of the UISegmentedControl's existing border. I would like to change the actual border of the UISegmentedControl to be 1px thick.